# Javascript stop and return to poster HTML 5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

This is my javascript which pause and play the HTML 5 video when a button is pressed but I want to stop the video instead of pausing and returning to the video poster how can I achieve that?

```
function vidplay() {
    var video = document.getElementById("bg-vid");
    var button = document.getElementById("play");
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have been able to find is to reset the source of the video. The other way to handle it would be to have a div with the poster image in that you swap out for the video.

The problem with this method is that by resetting the source you lose the playhead position so if that's important you'll also need to track the currentTime before resetting, and on play have the playhead set back to that currentTime value

```
<script>
    var vid=document.getElementById('bg-vid');
    vid.addEventListener("pause", resetVideo, false);

    function resetVideo() {
        // resets the video element by resetting the source
        this.src = "video.mp4" // **source of video**
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `load()` method (although I believe changing the `src` attribute implicitly calls it):

```
...
if (video.paused) {
  video.play()
} else {
  load();
}
...
```

**Note:** this method re-loads the resource, thus depending on caching settings it may be re-downloaded causing unnecessary bandwidth and CPU usage.